# How to get a single String item from List<MyList> Array list

Tags: android, json

I am working on recyclerview i am getting data from API in json format. So i created two Models. One is for my recycler view data and other is for my calendar view. I am successfully getting data in recycler view using custom adapter. now i want to get date from json response in my second model. I done this way.

How i am reading Date from JSON Response:

```
final List<MyEventsDateModel> dateModel = new ArrayList<>();
String date = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("eventStudentListIbfk2rel").optString("scheduledDate");
             String mainDate[] = date.split("T");
             String eventDate = mainDate[0];
             dateModel.add(new MyEventsDateModel(eventDate));
             callback.onSuccess(dateModel);
```

**MyEventsDateModel.Class**

```
public class MyEventsDateModel extends BaseModel {
private String myEventDate;

public MyEventsDateModel(String myEventDate) {
    this.myEventDate = myEventDate;
}

public MyEventsDateModel(Context actContext, List<MyEventsResponseModel> myEventsModel) {
}

public String getMyEventDate() {
    return myEventDate;
}

public void setMyEventDate(String myEventDate) {
    this.myEventDate = myEventDate;
}
}
```

now in on success method i have my date model which iam using like this:

```
public void onSuccess(List<MyEventsDateModel> dateModel) {
//NOW HERE I WANT TO GET getMyEventDate(); how can i do that?
        }
```

**Tried like this but it is saying nullPointerException**

```
 String myDate = myEventsDateModel.getMyEventDate();
    LoggerUtils.error("Date", "" + myDate);
    addDate(myDate);
```

<<- Why this question marked as duplicate? I know what is null pointer exception. I asked about Json parsing and getting each string from response in for loop. Please remove duplicate mark ->>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
MyEventsDateModel myEventsDateModel = dateModel.get(<PASS YOUR INDEX HERE>)
String myDate = myEventsDateModel.getMyEventDate();
LoggerUtils.error("Date", "" + myDate);
addDate(myDate);
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked out like charm! I dont know why @Tm Castelijns marked this as duplicate.